# Titanium, Android, Estimote iBeacon: how to create a

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules, ibeacon-android, estimote

I have a titanium app and I want to add iBeacon capability for android (with Estimote). The app must push a local notification when reaching the area of a beacon.

Can Anybody give some advice? From the examples in android SDK (https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) Estimote start listening for beacons in an activity. I want to do it for the whole app (maybe a subclass of `Application`?) but I don't know how to do it in a titanium module.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same here, did you find something? I've been trying to create this Application subclass to startMonitoring but have no idea on how to do this in a module =\

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueLustosa sorry but it's been more than 2 years and I really can't remember how I solved the issue... I even changed job, so I don't have the code anymore. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with titanium, but in my native android app, i created a service that listens for beacons and all activities can bind to that service and then access the received beacon information.

Don't know if this is a solution for Titanium though.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good Titanium Module for Bluetooth LE communication: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/6611

I used iOS version for my app development and it worked well. You can download trial and try it out but license costs $350.

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured it out but just in case....I have done something similar with Titanium and iBeacon for IOS. Once my app detects an iBeacon, it makes a REST API call to my server and it can send some notification back etc.

Basically here are the steps...

1. Find a Titanium ibeacon module.
   I used the [Joe Beuckman's](https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons) module for iOS...It is free and works fairly well.
   Here is [one for Android](https://github.com/m1ga/tibeacon) that google found me....Not tried it so no idea if this will work....
2. Raise an event when an iBeacon is detected and raise the notification / call some external service etc. Initially, I hardcoded the iBeacon UUID / Major / Minor so that my app would ignore any other iBeacons.

In the final version, I will filter off based on UUID only and let my server do the rest. However, you can try to do this anyway you like it.

Here is some sample code from the Beuckman's excellent module...And here is his complete code for a reference app...https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons-Example-App

```
TiBeacons.startMonitoringForRegion({
    uuid : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    identifier : "Test Region 1",
});

TiBeacons.startRangingForBeacons({
    uuid : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
    identifier : "Test Region 2 (group-specific)",
    major: 1
});

TiBeacons.startRangingForBeacons({
    uuid : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
    identifier : "Test Region 3 (device-specific)",
    major: 1,
    minor: 2
});
```

I had some trouble initially with testing if my iDevice was even catching any iBeacon signals. I used estimote and Radius network's iBeacon Locate app to ensure that my iOS device was in range and the transmitters were working.

Hope this helps.